# how to return all rows where string is substring of atribute

Tags: php, mysql

I have search of users on my website. I want to return all rows of users whose name  contains entered string or is equal to string.

It would look something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];    
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' OR **'$name' is substr of name**"
```

Comment: SQL 101: `WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'`.... now learn to use parameterised statements using MySQLi or PDO before you discover how easy it is to SQL inject code the way you've written it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
```

Using PDO:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=YourHost;dbname=YourDatabase", $username, $password);    
    $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'");    

    //fetch your data.....   

    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```